# How to avoid waiting of a worker

Tags: microservices, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I have a scenario to implement to trigger the auth token for 3rd party server using open id connect flow.

For authentication I'll be using headless browser to mimic the human interaction of adding credentials and clicking buttons etc.

I have created a diagram which will work but it will have wait time for a worker. Which can cause issues.

[image]

Is there any way we can  avoid this wait on the worker. One solution could be to use another worker to receive the token but that worker won't know what data and request to send to 3rd part API.

Is there any way we can either reduce this wait time on worker(by event-driven approach) or if we can use API request and data in 2nd worker?